# Unable to make ajax post request to controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
<script>
  function AddPayment() {

    debugger;
    var jsonData = JSON.stringify({
      "DefaultCashAccount": $("#hdnDefaultCashAccount").val(),
      "BillId": $("#lblBillId").val(),
      "PaymentMethodValue": $("#ddPaymentMethod").val(),
      "PaymentMethodName": $("#ddPaymentMethod option:selected").html(),
      "Amount": $("#textBoxAmount").val(),
      "Rounding": $("#txtRounding").val(),
      "CurrencyName": $("#ddcurrency").val(),
      "CurrencyValue": $("#ddcurrency option:selected").html(),
      "BankAccountId": $("#ddBankAccount").val(),
      "BankAccountName": $("#ddBankAccount option:selected").html(),
      "PrivateNotes": $("#lblPrivateNotes").val(),
      "DueDate": ("#lblDueDate").val(),
      "Balance": ("#lblBalance").val(),
    });
    $.ajax({
      type: "Post",
      url: "/BillDetailAndPayment/btnSavePayment_Click",
      async: false,
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      data: jsonData,
      success: function(data) {},
      error: function(msg) {
        debugger;
      }
    });

  } 
</script>

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult btnSavePaymentClick(BillDetailAndPaymentModel model) {
  //string val = lblBillId.Text;
  var bill = ((Bill) Session["billObj"]);

  CreateBillPaymentCreditCard(bill, model);
  return RedirectToAction("UploadHistory", "UploadHistory");
  // ClearControls();
  // Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myScript", "checkValidation();", true);
}

}

public class BillDetailAndPaymentModel {

  public string DefaultCashAccount {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public string BillId {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public SelectListItem PaymentMethod {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public SelectListItem Currency {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public SelectListItem BankAccount {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public string Amount {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public string Rounding {
    get;
    set;
  }

  public string PaymentMethodId {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public string PaymentMethodValue {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public string CurrencyName {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public string CurrencyValue {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public string BankAccountId {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public string BankAccountName {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public string PrivateNotes {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public DateTime DueDate {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public decimal Balance {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public EntityStatusEnum status {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public string PrivateNote {
    get;
    set;
  }
}
```

Hi above is my code for ajax post and controller and my model.I am trying to make ajax post request to controller action but I am not able to do that .I am stuck in this issue as I have tried to resolve the problem according to my knowledge. I am not able to make ajax post request to controller action. Please help with the best answers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like your URL isn't right. There is an difference with using an underscore. Maybe this is your problem. Otherwise how is the structure of your application?

Comment: did you tried changing your btnSavePayment_Click to btnSavePaymentClick? in AJAX